# \AtBeginDocument + \usetikzlibrary + remember picture = undefined \savepicturepage

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages

I'm writing a package that first checks whether the tikz package is loaded, then add some tikz libraries

However, this package has a conflict with "remember picture, overlay" option of tikzpicture

My MWE that embeds the content of the package into a single tex file:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\AtBeginDocument{\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In Texmaker (I don't know if it matters), this can generate the pdf file at  the initial build. However, if I build the .tex file one more time, it gives an error message: "Undefined control sequence. `\savepicturepage`"

(cf. `\usetiklibarary` part is inside the package and should come before `\usepackage{tikz}`, and that's why I use `\AtBeginDocument`.
For another reason, I should also use [remember picture, overlay] option)

Anyone knows why?

Comment: you can't load the library there, this is too late. With a current latex you can use another hook: `\AddToHook{env/document/before}{\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}}`

Comment: Without "remember picture, overlay" part, it seems okay to load the library there though

Comment: loading perhaps. But did you try to use it? Add a `\tikzmark{blub}` and you will get the same error. tikzmark uses the aux-file and so must be loaded before this file is processed.

Comment: Oh I see. I indeed cannot use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't generally load Ti*k*Z libraries at begin document.

With a current LaTeX you can do the loading *just before* begin document:

```
documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter % this will go in the .sty file
\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{tikz}{\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}}{}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you want this to work also with older versions of LaTeX, you need to load `etoolbox` and to use `\AtEndPreamble`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter % this will go in the .sty file
\@ifundefined{AddToHook}{%
    \RequirePackage{etoolbox}%
    \AtEndPreamble{%
      \@ifpackageloaded{tikz}{\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}}{}%
    }%
  }{%
    \AddToHook{begindocument/before}{%
      \@ifpackageloaded{tikz}{\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}}{}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still using older versions, so etoolbox may be the only option.
One final question: doesn't etoolbox make my build slow? I tend to be a little bit worried about using a multi-function package that might slow down my build.

Comment: @user182849 I see no reason to worry.